# Flutter FCM with dart

Tags: flutter

I want to send FCM when users click a button. I'm trying to send message with subscribeToken, but I haven't used Node.js so I don't know how to handle Firebase Function. Therefore I want to use dart language to send it. Is there any way to send FCM with dart language?

```
await http.post(
    'http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key=$serverToken',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(
      <String, dynamic>{
        'notification': <String, dynamic>{
          'body': 'this is a body',
          'title': 'this is a title',
        },
        'priority': 'high',
        'data': <String, dynamic>{
          'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
          'id': '1',
          'status': 'done'
        },
        'to': widget.gallery.author + widget.gallery.reference.id + 'like',
      },
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to send notifications with `dart` but only directly from your Flutter app. Because `Firebase Cloud Functions` have no `dart` implementation.

For this to work you will first have to add `http` as a dependency to your `pubspec.yaml` file.
How to install it: https://pub.dev/packages/http/install

Then create a `credentials.dart`.
Now, go to: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/settings/cloudmessaging

and copy the `Server key`.
(Replace the YOUR_PROJECT_ID with your actual Firebase project id in the url)

In the `credentials.dart` file write this:

```
const FCM_SERVER_KEY = ''; /// Put the Server key you copied here.
```

The `credentials.dart` file should be private and you should not upload to any source control.

Now accessing Google's FCM api with this helper class:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:path/to/credentials.dart' as credentials;

class Notifications {
  /// Handles sending FCM notifications
  /// using Google's FCM api.
  static Notifications get instance => Notifications();
  static const Map<String, dynamic> DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_DATA = {
    'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
    'type': 'default',
  };

  Future<String> send(
    String fcmToken, {
    String title,
    String body,
    Map<String, dynamic> data = DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_DATA,
  }) async {
    /// Sends a notification with the
    /// given title and body to the given
    /// FCM token.
    try {
      http.Response r = await http.post(
        'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'key=${credentials.FCM_SERVER_KEY}',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(
          <String, dynamic>{
            'notification': <String, dynamic>{
              'title': title,
              'body': body,
              'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            },
            'priority': 'high',
            'data': data,
            'to': fcmToken,
          },
        ),
      );

      return r.body;
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

To send a notification:

```dart
import 'package:path/to/notifications.dart';
final String fcmToken = '';
Notifications.instance.send(fcmToken);
/// fcmToken is the FCM token of the device you want to send the notification to
```

**How to get an fcmToken?**

Depending on what version of Firebase Messaging you are using you can get a messaging token for the user's device by calling:

```
String fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

Now when you call the `Notifications.send(fcmToken);` function the device associated with the `fcmToken` will recieve your notification.
In your case, you might send the notification to the gallery owner's device by giving the function their `fcmToken`.

I suggest you storing those tokens in a database. However, keep in mind that if the user logs in to their account on a different device their token will change and you will have to update it.

Comment: I added what I tried in question. I tired that code but it didn't work. What is difference with my code and your answer?

Comment: You are using the code I gave you in my answer, there is no difference. It doesn't work because you are sending the notification to: `widget.gallery.author + widget.gallery.reference.id + 'like'` and that is not an `fcmToken`.

Comment: I added code for getting the `fcmToken` to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: I used `widget.gallery.author + widget.gallery.reference.id + 'like'` because I used substribeTopic method in FirebaseMessaging. Then I don't have to change the token when the user change their device.

Comment: If you want to use topics then you have to send notifications to topics and this should be done using `node` and `Firebase Cloud Functions`. On the other hand if you want to send messages from your device it would be best to use the helper class I gave you. And in that casw you will have to use tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to send FCM without a service account which is used as firebase admin therefore the only way you can make it work is through firebase admin and the easiest way is to use firebase functions. You can watch a video on youtube on how to configure it solely for FCM